# Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime. I'm using jquery datepicker with asp.net and c# web forms and sql databse

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, runtime-error, datetimepicker

I have a text box in which i select the date from the datepicker. I then need to validate:
1. A date is selected
2. date selected is not a future date. only todays date or any previous date.
3. Regular hrs add over time hours on that date do not exceed 20-24 hrs.

I've an error "Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." Can I please get some help over this as I have spent days over this.

C# code:

```
protected void btnCreate_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTxt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);

            if (DateTxt.Text != "" && PName_dd.Text != "" && CCG_dd.Text != "" && CCL_dd.Text != "")
            {

                cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TSHistory(EmpId_Int, ProjectCode_Int, TSDate_dt, CCode_Int, TSRhours_nu, TSOhours_nu, JobDescp_vc) VALUES(@GEId, @Pcode, @date, @CCode, @Rhr, @Ohr, @job)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GEId", EmpID.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCode", PCode_txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", dt);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CCode", CCL_dd.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rhr", R_txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ohr", O_txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job", JobDesc_txt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emp", EmpID.Text);
                cmd.Connection = Cnn;
                Cnn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Cnn.Close();
                updateUserDetails();
                // displayTS();
                RefreshSrc();
                RefreshDatabase();


            }

            else
            {


                //  DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime();
                //   var total_hrs = 24;
                //   DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTxt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
                //   global.Text = "Done";

                if (DateTxt.Text == "")

                {
                    // Response.Write("<script>alert('PLease select date');</script>");
                    //  dateError.Text = "PLease select date";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Select date')", true);



                }


                else if (DateTxt.Text != "" && dt > DateTime.Today)

                {
                    // Response.Write("<script>alert('Invalid Date');</script>");
                    //  dateError.Text = "Invalid date";
                    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Invalid date')", true);


                }



            }




        }

       catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("Error: " + ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Aspx code:

```
 <div class="form-group col-sm-1">
   <asp:TextBox ID="DateTxt" placeholder="Date" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" 
                ReadOnly="True">
   </asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I think you should check `DateTxt.Text` property string, because the error indicates problem converting the textbox content into `DateTime` instance with specified format.

Comment: what could I do in order to fix that? @TetsuyaYamamoto

Comment: Depends on the value format inside `DateTxt.Text` property, it must be matched to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm` pattern, otherwise `FormatException` will thrown.

Comment: what is your  DateTxt.Text   value?? @samyafayaz

Comment: it is the date selected from the date picker. That is if i select 30th january 2019 in the textbox it shows 01/30/2019 @Anoos

Comment: It sounds like you're taking a human readable text form from the date picker - that may well be locale-sensitive. I'd strongly advise looking at whether your date picker allows you to convert the value to an ISO-8601 representation, which is more appropriate to transfer the value from the browser to the server.

Comment: Why don't you restrict your calender, to select only dates that are past with some JavaScript or maybe you can use Air DatePicker [Link](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/) and perform some client-side validation instead of server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make ReadOnly= "False"**

The contents of the TextBox control cannot be changed if ReadOnly="True".And that's why DateTxt text values remains empty("") and it is throwing an Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Finally! Thankyou so much :)

Comment: Hi. Actually the same error is showing again when i do not enter any date, **Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime**  Now when I do not enter any date or a future date is selected I want it to display an alert. I have posted the updated code. I would be grateful if your could help. Also, when i select a future date the following error is shown **Error: Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.**

Comment: Keep this code in IF CONDITION. `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTxt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);`

Answer (score 0):

As your text contains only date part, change your code as below,

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTxt.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: When I tried this Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("01/30/2019", "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); the out put was  1/30/2019 12:00:00 AM

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the code a little bit. Please check.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DateTxt.Text.Date, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces);
```

Comment: After I changed the ReadOnly to False and edited my code with yours it worked. Thanks!